# Appcelerator change sender name for Password reset

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy, arrowdb

Using the default appcelerator template Im sending a password reset request. The mail subject is

> Password reset request for My-wierd-appname-development

and at the end of the email it says:

> Regards,
>
> My-wierd-appname-development Team

This appname for development was a name I had no intention to show the end user. I've tried changing the `<name> entry` in tiapp.xml but the app name seems to be taken from what was initially entered in arrow db. Is there any place I can change this appname that appears in the mail without using custom mail templates?
Changing the subject could be done by setting the subject parameter in the `Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword` request, but it still uses the appname in the bottom. I just don't know where it gets this appname and where to change it?

Its also adding "development" to the end, does it show "production" in prod env mails?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just ended up using a custom template as it provided a lot more flexibility and options for editing sender names etc.